# Someone who knows how to sing

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe someone who knows how to sing and does it well but not quite professionally? "Amateur singer" doesn't seem to cut it.

Comment: Why don't you like *amateur singer*? Seems perfectly clear and apt to me.

Comment: How about "She's a ***really good*** singer."  That's a pretty common choice of words for that situation. Or "She's got a really good voice."

Comment: *Amateur* is synonymous with *non-professional* and it clearly matches your description. On the same line though, how about *dilettante singer* ?

Comment: "A singer is a person who sings. Anyone who is singing is a singer. Some people do it as a job (professional singer), others may sing without being paid (amateur singer)." (https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singer). There are professional singers, amateur singers, bathroom singers, ... However, "a good singer" drives homes the point well, as Jim already noted.

Comment: A [*talented singer*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22talented+singer%22). Pop Idol, X Factor, [Nation/Country] Has Talent, and The Voice; haven't any of  these *talent* shows taught us anything! :) See also [*Young talented singers*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22young+talented+singers%22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[songster](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/songster#songster__2)** or **songstress**

> A person who sings, especially fluently and skilfully

Answer (score 1):

A 'singer'. 'Amateur singer' would be fine too. Perhaps maybe a 'good singer' would convey the idea that the singer is not professional.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the word "vocalist," although just a synonym for "singer," has the shade of meaning you're looking for (or at least something like it). Often (though not always!) for professional singers we will clarify the genre: s/he's an opera singer, country singer, etc.